# Time difference with dotNET core on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core

I'm banging my head on the walls with this one so I am hoping somebody here can help me.

I've developed a rather simple application in dotNET core 3.1.
It's purpose is to query some things from the database, do something with it and then write the date and time back to the database.

When I run this on my development machine, everything works as expected, but as soon as I publish this app on the Kubernetes platform, the date and time shifts back two hours (I'm in GMT + 2)

At first I thought that the time was off on the Kubernetes nodes, but I checked it and it was ok.

Can somebody direct me in the right direction on how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you describe your environment in more detail? Is it hosted locally/ in cloud?

Comment: I'm running Kubernetes locally. It runs on Ubuntu 18.04. When I execute the _date_ command it gives me back the following: `Fri Apr 17 07:19:27 CEST 2020` which is the correct date and time. This is consistent on all the nodes.

Comment: When you exec to the pod is the time the same as on the node? https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-change-the-time-zone-for-a-docker-container/

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I finally figured it out. The pods in the cluster do not seem to have any knowledge about the timezone. The way I was able to resolve the issue was to add an environment variable called `TZ` and give IT the correct value. In my case: `Europe/Amsterdam`